# "I've no idea..." which is the right preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is the correct form?

"I've no idea *of* what word to use"

"I've no idea *about* what word to use"

"I've no idea what word to use"

Does the preposition change according to what follows "I've no idea"? For example, does "I've no idea...where she went" require the same preposition as the first sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you do not need a preposition in such cases. #3 is correct: "I have no idea what word to use."

I'm not sure what the general rule is or if there is one -- this is a pretty broad example. I think, though, that you don't need a preposition if what follows "I have no idea" (or similar phrases, of course) includes a verb, but you do need a preposition if it does not.

> I have no idea where to go.
>
> I have no idea how to fly an airplane.

But:

> I have no idea ABOUT that.
>
> I have no idea OF my own.
>
> I have no idea BEYOND Sally's last suggestion.